# Python Selenium stuck after page "loaded"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using these options with chrome version 99.0.4844.82:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('test_shit/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I tried `page_load_strategy` with all arguments, `none` just completely breaks my script

The problem in my code is in this part

```
        try:
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
            driver.get(url)
        except:
            print('DOESNT WORK')
            continue
        print('loaded url')
        title = driver.title.replace(',,', '"').replace('„', '"')
        print('got the title')
        text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text
        print('got the text')
```

It just gets stuck after `driver.get(url)`, the `print('loaded url')` never goes through.
I haven't encountered this problem until I tried to scrape Hindi websites, specifically these:

> https://www.abplive.com/states/delhi-ncr/delhi-transport-department-to-redesign-ten-dangerous-streches-with-the-help-of-iit-delhi-soon-2052577

> https://hindi.oneindia.com/topic/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%BC%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%98%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE

> https://www.tv9hindi.com/india/40-percent-fatal-accidents-due-to-rear-end-collisions-findings-of-audit-report-by-ministry-of-road-and-transport-935425.html

> https://hindi.news18.com/tag/road-accident/

It is very weird as sometimes it works, but most of the time it gets stuck on one.

To be clear: the text loads, it's there, even the favicon loads, the script just gets stuck.

I have been trying to solve this for hours, if anybody has any idea how to stop this I would be very greatful.

Comment: some servers may detect Selenium and block it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think that's the case as even the sites I listed in my post sometimes work, the thing is I want them to work 100% of the time as it's a sign of an unsolved issue underneath.

Comment: maybe you visit too often (too many requests in short time) and it sometimes block you for short time.

Comment: or maybe server sometimes has problem with too many users and it has no time respond for all requests. But if it doesn't send any information then we can't know what is the problem.

Comment: The page loads, the text is displayed,  I haven't been banned from them yet.

Comment: As I said: if it doesn't send any information then we can't know what is the problem. We can only guess and try to different methods - even solution for detected Selenium. Maybe some method will help. Severs may have complex system to detect bots/spamers/hackers and they block Selenium but when real human uses browser

Comment: What information exactly?

Comment: any information - i.e. warning or captcha in HTML, response with error 403, etc. But if it only stops then we can only try different methods and see if one of them work.

Comment: Well, as for any information, as I said, the page actually loads but selenium gets stuck AFTER it loads, the text is displayed, so its probably a 200 response

Comment: maybe browser works all time - ie. sever sends slowly endless data to block browser, and browser wait for end of data. maybe it would need to observe page in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox. but timeout should stop it. OR maybe there is some bug in driver and all this makes problem (other programs may also have mistakes) and you may wait for newer version.

Comment: 30 seconds isn't all that long to wait.  You might just set that higher.  Also try/catch your get() calls so you can log exceptions if there are any.  There are some sites which will infinitely load. (sometimes these are a/b marketing tests.... a pageloadstrategy of eager is worth trying there...)  Selenium will be reading readystate, and if it's constantly switching may not ever see that the page has loaded.   It should timeout after a certain period... though some drivers have a very long timeout period by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally managed to solve it. The problem was that I had a `time.wait(1)` at the end of my code, I just removed it from there and put `time.wait(3)` before `driver.get(url)`.

Comment: Wait why does this matter/make a difference i have exactly the same problem and sometimes its just stuck forever after it has loaded

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea

Comment: well, as crazy as it seems, changing time.sleep(1) to time.sleep(3) before executing driver.get() solved the issue for me (or made it rare enough). How is this possible?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, even after almost two years I'm still perplexed